# Help with the ave() function in R

Tags: r

I'm new to `R` and l hope anyone can help me with the following:

regarding the command below:

```
x$rank <- ave(x$fin, x$unique,FUN=rank)
```

The command works fine, but what i want is the order of `x$rank` to be reversed, so basically for example the highest value of `x$fin` is showing its rank as '10', l would like the rank for the highest value to be '1'.

Also can i have more than one field as the second argument (currently `x$unique`) if there is more than one field to make the row unique. If yes, how would i structure this.

Answer (score 5):

You can take the rank of -fin to get ranks inverted.
If you have several variables to group by, just add the to your arguments:

```
x$rank <- ave(-x$fin, x$unique1, x$unique2, FUN=rank)
```